# CMake CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR and CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR to set same path, but only latter 'works'

Tags: c, cmake, include

I'm using CMake in, so far as I can tell, the same way as I always use it.  The problem is that now `include_directories($(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR)/server/include)` results in my header files *not* being found.  When instead I use `include_directories($(CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR)/server/include)` they *are* found.

i.e. `$(CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR)` works, and `$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR)` doesn't.

The bizarre thing is that both of:

```
message(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/server/include)
message(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/server/include)
```

give:

```
/home/username/projects/repo/server/include
```

So why does one work while the other doesn't?

Comment: Have you inserted `message(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/server/include)` into the **same file** and **same function**, which executes `include_directories($(CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR)/server/include)`? Note, that if some function dereferences a variable, then the dereference is performed according to the **caller scope**, not in the scope of the file which defines the function.

Comment: Quoting from the [docs of `include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html): "Relative paths are interpreted as relative to the current source directory." All CMake functions that accept paths do so. And that's why you write `include_directories(server/include)` and call it a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(FOO)` is not the correct syntax to refer to the cmake variable `FOO`. You need to use `${FOO}` instead. Neither of the uses of `include_directories` should work, unless the build system interprets the path `$(CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR)/server/include`.

Note that you're using the proper syntax for the `message` commands.

The `message` command

```
message($(CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR)/server/include)
```

prints

```
$(CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR)/server/include
```

demonstrating the issue.

I recommend using the `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` instead of `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` btw in all cases except for rare exceptions where you know that the toplevel `CMakeLists.txt` is located in a directory with specific contents. The former version is easier to recombine when used as part of a larger project via `add_subdirectory`.

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/server/include)
#                    ^                        ^
```

Note that the use of `target_include_directories` usually is preferrable to the use of `include_directories`, since the former allows restricts the targets the include directories are applied to to the one specifically mentioned. It also would allow you to make the include directories to targets linking a cmake library target, if desired.